# Return type of QFont() constructor in Qt

Tags: qt, fonts

I have passed a font family name as parameter to QFont constructor:

```
QFont* font = new QFont("Mongolian Bati");
```

later i'll be using this font family to my Qlabel:
`label->setFont(*font);`

**Here how do we know that the loaded font is Mongolian Bati ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you are passing the font family into the constructor:

```
QFont(const QString & family, int pointSize = -1, int weight = -1, bool italic = false)
```

So to get the family name back from the object you need to call the [`family()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#family) method:

```
font->family(); // Should be 'Mongolian Bati'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `font` from your label using the [`font()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#font-prop) method and then verify that it is the desired one using the [`family()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#family) method:

```
if (label->font().family() == "Mongolian Bati")
    // All ok
else
    // something went wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply pnezis. It worked for me finally.